# Кракозябры в расширении chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Я создал страницу, открылл ее как файл в браузере и все русские буквы были нормальные, но когда я сделал расширение с этой страницей, все русские буквы превратились в кракозябру. Кодировка и там и там utf-8 без bom.

Страница: https://prnt.sc/tekzcx,

Расширение: https://prnt.sc/tekznc

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "CloseTab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "options_page": "index.html",
  "description": "Таб",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

[index.html](https://pastebin.com/zp9u3KHf):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title">Последняя сессия</h1>
        <h1 class="history">История</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="list-header">
                <button>Открыть все</button>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="itemaction">
                    <div class="itemremove"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="itemaction">
                    <div class="itemicon"></div>
                    <div class="itemtitle">Test</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимальный код расширения

Comment: добавил код манифеста

Comment: Добавьте еще и `index.html`

Comment: добавил и index

Comment: Для форматирования кода используйте `\`\`\`` :) Попробуйте в `<head>` добавить `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: спасибо, теперь буквы нормальные)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в `<head>` на index.html

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```